# Changing Auto Layout constant doesn't update its frame

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uibutton, autolayout

I've created a little info view I'd like to add as a subview to a UIVisualEffectView. On my info view I created a free form xib and used Auto Layout for all the UILabels and one UIButton. The goal here is that **Start, Pull** and **Sled** are all optional so if that data doesn't exist I want to collapse those UILabels. I've accomplished this by updating their **equal height** constraint to 0.

**my  problem** is when some or all of those optional UIlabels collapse I want to update the `UIView`'s frame's height so things are tidy and don't potentially have gaps.

[image]

I do the below to update the constraints I've tagged in IB.

```
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        for constraint in view.constraints {
            if let identity = constraint.identifier {
                if labelTags.contains(identity) {
                    print("Before: \(view.frame)")
                    constraint.constant = labelHeight
                    view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
                    print("After: \(view.frame)")
                }
            }
        }
    }

Before: (5.0, 101.0, 50.0, 25.0)
After: (5.0, 101.0, 50.0, 25.0)
Before: (58.0, 101.0, 101.0, 25.0)
After: (58.0, 101.0, 101.0, 25.0)
Before: (5.0, 129.0, 39.0, 25.0)
After: (5.0, 129.0, 39.0, 25.0)
Before: (47.0, 129.0, 23.0, 25.0)
After: (47.0, 129.0, 23.0, 25.0)
Before: (5.0, 157.0, 45.0, 25.0)
After: (5.0, 157.0, 45.0, 25.0)
Before: (53.0, 157.0, 63.0, 25.0)
After: (53.0, 157.0, 63.0, 25.0)
```

After the constraints are updated I attempt to determine the view's frame by loops the views subview and get the max height like so:

```
    var height:CGFloat = 0.0
    for v in self.view.subviews {
        if (v.frame.origin.y + v.frame.size.height) > height {
            height = (v.frame.origin.y + v.frame.size.height)
        }
    }

    self.frame.size.height = height
```

On first load **getting the new frame height doesn't work because the UILabels frames don't update after updating their constraints.** Here is the kicker, the same code runs on orientation change and it works! When I rotate back to portrait all my `UILabels` are lined up nicely and the `UIView` is pulled up snuggly under the `UIButton`!

Any direction would be greatly appreciated, I've been at this for two days. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

`self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` was indeed the winner! In my case timing was everything.

I have never have paid that close attention but the below appear to be more of a 'suggestion' to the OS where as `layoutIfNeeded()` is immediate.

```
self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Comment: Calling `view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` won't cause an immediate layout pass.  Call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` for that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Call `layoutIfNeeded()`, which will force a redraw on the views that have AutoLayout constraint changes. It will also call `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, so you can do any additional work there.